# How to incorporate AbstractTableModel in a MVC design pattern

Tags: java

I need some help understanding how to incorporate a custom table model within [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/mvc-136693.html#) MVC design pattern. I am confused with the fact that I need to extend the AbstractTableModel class for my custom table model to be implemented but currently I have the AbstractModel class to keep track of all state changes. Would it suffice to create a MVC for just the table model and use it's firetablecellUpdated, etc? Please help me understand this better. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TableModel is the "Model" in MVC design, so the Model is responsible for storing the data and notifying the view when the data changes. The AbstractTableModel provides the fireXXX methods to make it easy for you to notify the view (JTable) when the data changes.

If you want to know how to write a custom TableModel then take a look at the section from the Swing tutorial on [Creating a TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) for a minimal implementation of a TableModel.

If you want to see a more complex implementation of a TableModel then take a look at:

1. the source code of the DefaultTableModel. The source is included with the JDK, usually in a file called "src.zip".
2. the [Row Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) which is a generic TableModel for display custom Objects. You will still need to implement a couple of methods to show the data from your object that you want displayed.